# Any way to do a selective wildcard exclude in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Suppose I have a Java project with a bunch of sources in src/main/java, and some further sources in src/main/java/myfolder:

```
src/main/java/myfolder/a.java
src/main/java/myfolder/b.java
src/main/java/myfolder/c.java
...
src/main/java/myfolder/z.java
```

From this folder I only want to include a.java and b.java. Is there any easy way to do this?

If Gradle include/excludes worked intuitively, I would expect this to work:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      include 'src/main/java/**'
      exclude 'main/java/myfolder/**'
      include 'main/java/myfolder/a.java'
      include 'main/java/myfolder/b.java'
    }
  }
}
```

But the exclude overwrites the subsequent includes.

Comment: I don't think the android plugin searches in 'main/java' what happens if you remove the exclude? I would imagine only a.java and b.java are included.

Answer (score 0):

The order you specify includes & excludes in is not relevant. Think of them like a set of filters:

- A file that does not match any includes will be filtered out
- A file that matches any exclude will be filtered out

In your case I would try using only includes

- include a.java
- include b.java
- include that includes everything *except* files under 'myfolder'

For implementing that last include I would look at passing a closure to the include method rather than a match pattern: [http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html#include(groovy.lang.Closure)](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html#include%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)